# which headers from the cookie I should use

Tags: cookies, httpresponse

I need to develop a program who need to sign in to a site by Python and then I need to get information from the site.
I have questions about the cookies.
after I make HTTP post request (username and password) I'm getting cookies.
how do i know which headers from the cookie I should use for the next request?
for example, this is the cookie I got from the post request

```
    Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=238FC46C4B1ACDA700ED8A135B4527865D7DA8098E818F56E10764DE6F5CE6D6BBAADD0483682E93FCB4BDF4D8A0F68041DCAD704C6B3A0955AD0C74852E44E31B06403D37C5C448DF24633DBD4909451248B42783B07D855897BF3E4A68C453; expires=Mon, 25-Nov-2019 18:29:34 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: rennabtuohtiweikooc=סבטלנה; expires=Mon, 25-Nov-2019 18:29:34 GMT; path=/
```

should i use the expires headers? what about the path?

where can i find a good article about this?
thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a good article who explain everything :

```
https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2009/05/05/http-cookies-explained/
```

good luck!